# HTML EMAIL - picture re-sizing in a table

Tags: html, image, html-email, css

Okay so my problem is I want to have an image on my HTML emails that automatically scales to the size of the page, with a max width of 400px.

I have no problems creating this on its own by using the below code:

```
<div style="max-width:400px">
<img src="example.jpg" style="max-width:100%">
</div>
```

However as soon as I put this code in a table (as I use lots of tables to create my HTML emails) it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: A lot of email agents aren't very good at reading CSS or inline-styling. If you want consistency in how the email will look, you may need to need to make some compromises. Take a look at HTML email boilerplate as a starting point. http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

Answer (score 2):

It's fine for the most part, as long as your table has a percentage width. You want `max-width:400px;` for the image, and it needs to be in a fluid width (percentage based) table container for it to work. Bear in mind `max-width` is unsupported in outlook, which may break your layout when viewed in a smaller window.

Also, div's have few (reliable) uses in email. Stick to tables unless you're using divs for special uses like hiding things with `overflow:hidden;`

Personally I'm not a fan of fluid emails. I use a `@media-query` in my `<style>` tag to resize instead.

Comment: is @media-query supported by Outlook and other Major email clients?

Comment: No. But why worry about people reading their emails in a small desktop window? Most HTML emails are not fluid and are designed for a 640 pixel desktop window. People who design fluid emails keep everything in one column and keep the text small so that text fits in a mobile email client. @media-query allows us to resize text, images, and table elements to clients that support it, which is the majority of mobile email clients (iOS mail, Android mail, WP7, but not gmail). Clients that don't support it will ignore it and all css inside it.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to place your image in a table and use @media to alter what happens. (I put some code in below)

1. Set the table width to the largest size of the image you need. (Also set the td width to the same. if you don't once the media query kicks in it will screw around with some of your sizing.)
2. Apply the class to the table and to the image.
3. Also make sure you put a width and height on your image. Some email clients (ie. outlook older versions) won't size the image correctly. The class is designed to fix the image sizes.
4. I would also recommend using an HTML 5 Doctype (  ). Most information out there says to use a XHTML transitional Doctype. But I've found great results with the HTML5 Doctype, especially with responsive image scaling.

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
    *[class=imgResize] {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="imgResize">
    <tr>
        <td width="400">
            <img src="example.jpg" width="400" height="200" style="display:block;" class="imgResize">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```